# Changing default colors of a specific program

Tags: command-line, colors

I am using [Todolist](http://todolist.site/) program in console. The dates are in blue color and it is hard to see them. I have seen some ways to change the general settings of the console:

[Changing the colors of lxterminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442887/changing-the-colors-of-lxterminal)

[Changing colour of text and background of terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal)

However I do only want to change the colors of `Todolist` program which runs in the console.

Is there a way to change these default colors? I was thinking of creating an alias of `Todolist` program in `./bashrc` with an specific configuration of PS1, but I haven't been able to get it.

I am using LXTerminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a link or some background information about `Todolist`?

Comment: http://todolist.site

Comment: I don't use the program or know how to install it but I looked at the contents of the [zip file](https://github.com/gammons/todolist) and `~/todolist-master/vendor/github.com/fatih/color/README.md` maybe of interest.

Comment: I have tried considering the @DKBose 's answer, but without success.  I installed `go get github.com/fatih/color`  but it does not let me change the colors. 'color.Cyan("Prints text in cyan.")
bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `'"Prints text in cyan."''` Any other ideas?

Comment: In that case, consider using another terminal emulator which offers you the option of having different profiles.