# Highlight user@device in terminal

Tags: console

Is it possible to highlight the "user@termial:" part written in the console. If I use several commands in a row which all produce large output it would be easier to determine where the last command was.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPu8p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .bashrc you can change the colors

You are looking for the following line

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[01;36m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the file. However I am not very familiar with ANSI colors. Could you change the line so I have a for example blue background for the line? I changed some values ( all 33m to 44m) and reopened my console several times and nothing changed. Does this modification need a reboot or some additional settings?

Comment: Take a look at this answer 

[link](http://askubuntu.com/a/123306/223798)

If you need further assistance feel free to ask

Comment: Ok now it worked. I had to uncomment the line saying: "force_color_prompt=yes". For the colours I used an ANSI-Table. Thanks for your help.