# How to install gnome-terminal 3.18.3 (from Ubuntu 16.04) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome, 16.04, gnome-terminal

I am trying to install the gnome-terminal 3.18.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.

The reason is want to have the username@computer name colored:

[image: image of username@computer colored]

Ubuntu 14.04 has gnome-terminal 3.6.2 by default. This is what I have tried so far:

Runned:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -f gnome-terminal
```

But it says gnome-terminal is already in the newest version.

I found the 3.18.3 package [HERE](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/gnome-terminal) but I do not know how to install it. Once extracted the `gnome-terminal_3.18.3-1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz` file there is a python script gnome-terminal-wrap, I guessed it was the installer, but didn't worked.

Does someone know how to install it?

If this is not possible, is there a way to color the username@computer text?

PD: Or installing gnome 3.18....

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updating gnome-terminal would not make the prompt colored. The terminal emulator just obeys instructions, even if you updated it the shell setup would still instruct it to display monochrome prompt. As others correctly pointed out, the shell setup should be changed to use colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit ~/.bashrc and apply the change yourself.

Open up ~/.bashrc and look for the following line:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

Remove the # from the beginning of the line and save.

You will have to source the file for the change to apply. If you reboot everything should work.

If you want to change the colour as well, see this: [Changing colors for user, host, directory information in terminal command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the debian package from this link http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-terminal and simply install it with *dpkg* or *ubuntu software center*
if you have problem with the dependencies you can do `sudo apt-get install -f` for fixing it.

Comment: There is a dependency that is not installed and doesn't install with sudo apt-get install -f. However the Tobias answer solved my problem, adding the color. Thank you anyway.