# Change Lubuntu QTerminal text color?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, customization, bashrc, colors

I want to change my terminal text color, it's gray right now and I want to set it as white, if possible white bold.

I already try to find how to do that with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt), where I tried to edit the `.bashrc` file:

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`

but I couldn't the correct plate to change it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click “File” → “Preferences” to open the Terminal settings window and under “Appearance” choose a “Color scheme” that fits your needs, for example “WhiteOnBlack”:

[image: qterminal settings window]

To try different color schemes you can move the settings window so that you see the terminal window again and just click “Apply” after making a selection.