# WSL Ubuntu bash - Changing colors for user, host, directory information

Tags: bash, themes, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Ubuntu 18.04 under Windows Subsystem for Linux, the color for the user, host and directories always have same color, if I want to change the theme, all of them change,

In Kali Linux under WSL, everything works pretty fine, also I have been to this page [Changing colors for user, host, directory information in terminal command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt) - but it doesn't helped me. I want to change colors bcoz it's so bad when everything is in same color except if you open file in nano or in something else then there is difference in colors but otherwise everything have same color.

I also tested installing Ubuntu WSL on two different computers but still they had same Issue, let me show you the pic. [I blurred some space bcoz of privacy but you'll get Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKd2I.png)

I would be so glad if you would help me :), Anyways thanks for reading my question!

Comment: WSL isn't designed to give you full Linux capabilities; that it works at all is amazing. Virtualization with VMware, VirtualBox, or other virtual engines is the preferred solution, BTW, which version of Ubuntu did you use? If 18.04, try 19.10, or vice versa,

Answer (score -2):

WSL isn't designed to give you full Linux capabilities; that it works at all is amazing. Virtualization with VMware, VirtualBox, or other virtual engines is the preferred solution,