# why does ($) appear in the second line

Tags: command-line, relinux

I don't understand why this $ apprear in the second line:

[image: Terminal Prompt]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add the output of: `echo $PS1`

Comment: Your prompt ($PS1) is no doubt set to include a LF (line-feed) character. Change it to whatever you want it to be.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing colors for user, host, directory information in terminal command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt)